# $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuously differentiable function (of class $C^1$). Show that mapping f can not be one-to-one mapping.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, manifolds

$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuously differentiable function (of class $C^1$). Show that mapping $f$ cannot be one-to-one mapping.

Let $D_1F(x,y) \neq 0$ for all $(x,y)$ for some open subset A and consider the function $g: A \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by the equality $$g(x,y) = (f(x,y),y)$$

Not sure if I'm doing it right so far, but how would I generalize it to $C^1$ mappings $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, $n > m$?

Comment: what exactly is your question? Did you intend to write $n>m$

Comment: $C^0$ suffices.  For the general case it might be easier to assume $C^1$, but for the $2\to 1$ case it suffices to use connectedness of continuous images of connected sets.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Sorry! Fixed

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't answer the question of how you would generalize to $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ with $n>m$. (user99680 mentions invariance of domain, which is one way to use only $C^0$ for the general case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are circles in ${\mathbb R}^n$ for $n > 1$, but no one-to-one images of circles in $\mathbb R$: any connected set in $\mathbb R$ can be disconnected by removing one point, a circle requires two.

Comment: Are you assuming there is a local homeomorphism in order to use this argument?

Comment: Nothing to do with local homeomorphism.  If $f: X \to Y$ is  continuous and $C \subseteq X$ is connected, then $f(C)$ is also connected.  If $f(C) \backslash \{y\}$ is disconnected, and $f^{-1}(y)$ consists of a single point $x$ of $X$, then $C \backslash \{x\}$ must be disconnected.

Comment: Isn't the stereographic projection one-to-one?

Comment: But it's undefined at the north pole (or maps it to infinity, depending on your point of view).

Answer (score 1):

for $r \in [0,1]$ define $$U_{r} = f(\{r\}\times(0,1))$$
if $f$ be one-to-one then $f$ over $\{r\}\times(0,1)$ is one-to-one for every $r$ and $U_{r}$ will be an open set in $\mathbb{R}$. now $U_{r}$s are uncountable distinct open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ and this one is'nt possible to take uncountable distinct opens in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why not? You can form an open interval (a,b) for every pair of Reals. Maybe you mean an open subset of Reals with uncountably-many components?

Comment: @user99680 I say that it is not possible to take an uncountable family of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ that are distinct.

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, but then it is (pairwise) disjoint, not distinct.

Comment: @user99680 my mean is that intersection of every to open sets is empty

Comment: O.K, so we agree ;).

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:restrict the map to a compact subset K with non-empty interior  of $\mathbb R^2$. Then $f|_K$ is a continuous bijection between compact and Hausdorff , so it is a homeomorphism. Choose an open subset of K; its image will be open in $\mathbb R $, which cannot happen, e.g., by invariance of domain. For the second case, you should have $n>m$, or the injection $(a_1,..,a_n) \rightarrow (a_1,..,a_n,0,0,..,0)$ will be a counterexample .